# Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 404

Tags: r, web-scraping, data-visualization

I'm new to data scraping and R. I am trying to scrape a website to extract data about the economy. I'm using rvest and tidyverse, but everytime I run the code, it says:  Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 404. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
library(scales)
library(knitr)
library(lubridate)
url <- "https://www.bls.gov/regions/west/ca_oakland_md.htm"
timevalues <- seq(as.Date("2020/03/01"), as.Date("2020/08/30"), by = "month")
head(timevalues)
[1] "2020-03-01" "2020-04-01" "2020-05-01" "2020-06-01" "2020-07-01" "2020-08-01"
unitedata<- function(x){
full_url <- paste0(url, x)
full_url
}
finalurl <- unitedata(timevalues)
head(finalurl)
[1] "https://www.bls.gov/regions/west/ca_oakland_md.htm2020-03-01"
[2] "https://www.bls.gov/regions/west/ca_oakland_md.htm2020-04-01"
[3] "https://www.bls.gov/regions/west/ca_oakland_md.htm2020-05-01"
[4] "https://www.bls.gov/regions/west/ca_oakland_md.htm2020-06-01"
[5] "https://www.bls.gov/regions/west/ca_oakland_md.htm2020-07-01"
[6] "https://www.bls.gov/regions/west/ca_oakland_md.htm2020-08-01"
BlsScrape <- function(x) {
page <- x 
laborforce <- page %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes('.sub0') %>% html_text()%>% as.data.frame()
monthchange <- page %>% reaurld_html() %>% html_nodes('.sub1') %>% html_text()%>% as.data.frame()
values<- page %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes('.datavalue') %>% html_text()%>% as.data.frame()
chart <- cbind(laborforce, monthchange, values)
names(chart) <- c("Laborforce", "Monthchange", "Values")
chart <- as_tibble(chart)
return(chart) }
tried <- map_df(finalurl, BlsScrape)
Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 404. 
head(tried)
Error in head(tried) : object 'tried' not found
```

Comment: When I copy those URLs from `finalurl` into my browser I get a (custom) 404 -file not found page. What exactly is the page you are trying to scrape?

Comment: https://www.bls.gov/regions/west/ca_oakland_md.htm

Comment: When why are you pasting those dates into the URL? It's not clear to me what you are trying to do.

Comment: That was the formula I was taught with how to do it. But when I try on my own outside of what I was taught, I can't get it right. The goal is to data scape a website and visualize it using the data found. I'm trying to become good in this skill, so this is extra practice.

Comment: Try using the BLS's API for querying the data.  See this page for the introduction and example code in R. https://www.bls.gov/developers/

Comment: I will try. Thank you kindly.